# Read the value that a cell contains when selected in a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the 2 dataframes below:

```
Name<-c("John","Bob","Jack")
Number<-c(3,3,5)
NN<-data.frame(Name,Number)

d1<-c("a",NA,"b")
d2<-c("a","a","b")
d3<-c(NA,NA,"b")
d4<-c("a","c","b")
d5<-c(NA,"b","b")
NN2<-data.frame(Name,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
```

The `NN` contains the names and the count of non-NA inputs for every name in `NN2`. I created a shiny app which displays a datatable of `NN`. I want to be able to click on every name and get a second table with the relative row of `NN2` as you will see if you click on `John`. The issue is that instead of recognizing which name I chose with row and column which I do with: `if(input$x3_cells_selected[,1]==1&input$x3_cells_selected[,2]==1)` I would like to recognize it by the name automatically. That means that when I click on `John` in the 1st table the algorithm will not see 1st column-1st row but will search for `John` data in the 2nd table.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)

fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x3')

  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x4')
  )

)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$x3 = DT::renderDataTable(datatable(NN,selection = list(target="cell",mode="single")))

  second<-reactive({
    req(input$x3_cells_selected)
    if(input$x3_cells_selected[,1]==1&input$x3_cells_selected[,2]==1){
      NN2[1,2:6]
    }

  })

  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable(datatable(second(),rownames = F))



})
```

Comment: I don't understand. If you get the row index and the column index, what is the difficulty to get the cell value?

Comment: In a few words If I print the result of input$x3_cells_selected it will be "1,1" (if Iclick on 1st row-1st column) but I want it to be "John".

Comment: So why don't you do `NN[input$x3_cells_selected[,1], input$x3_cells_selected[,2]]` ?

Comment: I adjusted your answer to my original issue succesfully thanks